# Programmatically Send Transactions From a Wallet Using Javascript

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-serialization-lib, nami-wallet

I am building an application that has a hot wallet that stores ADA that my user has deposited. After some business logic is met, I want to transfer funds from my hot wallet to another address. How do I programmatically send ADA from my wallet to another user? I am currently using the Cardano-serialization-library but it prompts you to enter your password into your wallet extension for the transactions to go through. How do I programmatically send transactions from my wallet to my user without putting in a password in my wallet extension? My application is built on MERN stack so it needs to be in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already hold access to wallet private keys, you dont need to "interact" with a wallet extension, you already have all you need to derive the keys, addresses, fetch inputs from query layer of your choice and then construct/submit transaction.

If - instead - you're interacting via extension to access user's wallet, doing it without user prompt should NOT be possible unless using an insecure wallet with bad practices (i.e. either does not care about user security to authorize transactions OR allows bulk mode of transactions to be allowed at once, both of which can be easy targets for scam).